# Django/Python formsets

Tags: jquery, django, internet-explorer-9, inline-formset

I am trying to upload multiple file attachments using django's  inline_formset. 
So, basically I am generating the formset dynamically using jquery and allow the user to upload multiple files.
My implementation works fine on Firefox and Chromium; however on IE9 this does not work.
I do not get any error messages or anything like that; however, I do not see the uploaded files being saved on the server.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Thank you,

Here is the code for the issue I am having:

views.py: (relevant portion only)

```
@login_required
def save_patent_idea_page(request):

    if request.method =='POST':

            form = PatentIdeaSaveForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                    idea = PatentIdea.objects.create(
                    industry = form.cleaned_data['industry'],
                    abstract = form.cleaned_data['abstract'],
                    description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
                    title= form.cleaned_data['title'],

                    #############################################
                    #share_ind = form.cleaned_data['share_ind'] #   
                    #############################################

                    user = request.user
                    )

                    idea.save()

                    patentfileformset = 
                       PatentFileFormset(request.POST, request.FILES,   instance=idea)



                    if patentfileformset.is_valid():
                            patentfileformset.save();

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    '/user/ideas/'
                    )
    else:
            form = PatentIdeaSaveForm(initial={
                    'description':'Please Type your desc here ....',
                    'title':'Specify a title here ....',
                    'abstract':'Type your abstract here ....'
                    })

            patentfileformset = PatentFileFormset(instance=PatentIdea())


    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form' : form,
        'patentfileset' : patentfileformset
})

    return render_to_response('patentidea_save.html', variables)
```

########################### END views.py

models.py (relevant portion only):

```
class PatentIdea(models.Model):
    industry = models.ForeignKey(PatentIndustry)
    abstract = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2100, blank=True, null=True)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)

    ######################################################################
    #share_ind = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)#
    ######################################################################

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ###############################################################################
    #PatentFile = models.FileField(upload_to='patentideas', blank=True, null=True)#
    ###############################################################################
    Last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.abstract)

class PatentFile(models.Model):

    patentidea = models.ForeignKey(PatentIdea)
    PatentFile = models.FileField(upload_to='patentideas', blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    patentfilename = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

######################### END models.py

forms.py (relevant portion only):

```
 PatentFileFormset = inlineformset_factory(PatentIdea, PatentFile,
                                      formset = BaseInlineFormSet,
                                      formfield_callback=custom_field_callback,
                                      extra=4, max_num=0, can_delete=True)

def custom_field_callback(field):
    if field.name == 'FieldOfStudy':
            return field.formfield(label='Field Of Study');
    if field.name == 'grad_month':
            return field.formfield(label='Graduation');
    if field.name == 'grad_year':
            return field.formfield(label='');
    if field.name == 'delete':
            return field.formfield(label='Delete');
    if field.name == 'posDesc':
            return forms.CharField(label='Position Desc', max_length=600,
                   widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':'100','rows':'4'}));
    if field.name == 'emp_fr_month':
            return field.formfield(label='From');
    if field.name == 'emp_to_month':
            return field.formfield(label='To');
    if field.name == 'emp_fr_year':
            return field.formfield(label='');
    if field.name == 'emp_to_year':
            return field.formfield(label='');
    if field.name == 'PatentFile':
            return forms.FileField(label='',
            widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'patentfile_cls'}));
    if field.name == 'patentfilename':
            return forms.CharField(label='',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True, 'size':10,
                    'class':'patentfile_cls2'}));

    else:
            return field.formfield();
```

######################### END forms.py

patentidea_save.js (relevant portion only):

```
   $('#id_patent_file_add').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    //alert('Hi 1');        
    var count = $('#id_display_patentfile_list ul')
        .children('li[id^="display_patentfile-"]').length
    var tmplMarkup = $('#patentfile-template').html();
    var compiledTmpl = _.template(tmplMarkup, { id : count});
    $('div[id="id_tmp_form"]').empty();
    $('div[id="id_tmp_form"]').append(compiledTmpl);
    popup = $('#id_patentfile_set-'+count+'-PatentFile').trigger('click');

//      $(popup.document).ready(function() {
//              alert(popup.selector);
//              console.log('ready');
//              $(popup).on('unload', function () {
//                      console.log('unloaded');   
//              });
//      });



    });

    $('#id_tmp_form').on('change','input[id^="id_patentfile_set-"][id$="-PatentFile"]',
    function() {

    var count = $('#id_display_patentfile_list ul')
           .children('li[id^="display_patentfile-"]').length

    uploaded_filename = $('#id_patentfile_set-'+count+'-PatentFile').val();
    $('#id_patentfile_set-'+count+'-patentfilename').val(uploaded_filename);
    //alert(uploaded_filename+this.files[0].size);
    var filesize = this.files[0].size;
    //alert(filesize);

    dots = uploaded_filename.split(".")
    //get the part AFTER the LAST period.
    fileType = dots[dots.length-1];

    var tmp_content = $('div[id="patentfile-'+count+'"]').clone();

    $('#id_patent_file').append(tmp_content);

    $('div[id="id_tmp_form"]').empty();

    $('#id_patentfile_set-'+count+'-PatentFile').attr('val',uploaded_filename);


    $('#id_display_patentfile_list ul').append('<li id=display_patentfile-'+count+
    ' class="attachment_cls"></li>');

   var attachment_envelope = $('<div id="id_ae-'+count+'" class="drawing"></div>').css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    border: '2px solid #228B22',
    width: '125px',
    height: '80px'

    });


    attachment_envelope.appendTo($('#display_patentfile-'+count));

    $('<span>'+fileType+'  </span>').appendTo(attachment_envelope);
    $('<span>'+filesize+'KB</span>').appendTo(attachment_envelope);
    $('<a href="#" class="delete_button_cls3"'+
    'title="click to delete" id="id_delete_patent_file-'+count+
    '"><img width="12" height="12" alt="delete sign"'+
    'src="/staticfiles/images/delete.png"></a>').appendTo(attachment_envelope);

    $('<hr />').appendTo(attachment_envelope);

    $('<span  class="filename_cls">'+uploaded_filename+'</span>').
     appendTo(attachment_envelope);

    var count = $('#id_display_patentfile_list ul').
         children('li[id^="display_patentfile-"]').length


    $('#id_patentfile_set-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count);
    });
```

################# END patentidea_save.js

patentidea_save.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block external %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}js/patentidea_save.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Save Patent Idea{% endblock %}
{# {% block head %}Save Patent Idea{% endblock %} #}
{% block content %}

    <form method ="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

    <div id="id_block_title">
            {{ form.title.errors }}
            <label for="id_title"  class="required">Title</label>
            {{ form.title}}
    </div>

    <div id="id_block_industry">
            {{ form.industry.errors }}
            <label for="id_industry" class="required" >Industry</label>
            {{ form.industry}}
    </div>


    <div id="id_block_abstract">

            {{ form.abstract.errors }}
            <label for="id_abstract" class="required" >Abstract</label>
            {{ form.abstract}}
            <br><span id="remainingCount1">000</span> characters left

    </div>

    <div id="id_block_description">
            {{ form.description.errors }}
            <br><br>
            <label for="id_description" class="required">Description</label>
            {{ form.description}}
            <br><span id="remainingCount2">000</span> characters left<br><br>

    </div>

    <div id="id_block_uploadfile">


            <span id="id_PatentFile" title='Please Load Related File(s), if any'>
            Load Related File(s)</span>
            <a id="id_patent_file_add" href="#" class="patent_file_add_cls">[Add]</a>
            <div id="id_tmp_form"></div>
            {{ patentfileset.management_form }}
             <div id="id_patent_file">
            {% for pform in patentfileset %}
              <div id="id_patent_file-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                {{ pform.as_p }}
             </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div id="id_display_patentfile_list">
            <ul>

            </ul>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div id="id_block_submit">
            <input type="submit" id="id_submit_patentidea" value="Save">
            <input type="button" id="id_cancel_patentidea" 
            onClick="parent.location='{% url cpit.views.main_page %}'"
            value="Cancel">
    </div>



</form>

<script type="text/html" id="patentfile-template">
 <div id="patentfile-<%= id %>" style="display:none">
    <p>
    <label for="id_patentfile_set-<%= id %>-PatentFile">PatentFile:</label>
    <input id="id_patentfile_set-<%= id %>-PatentFile" type="file" 
    name="patentfile_set-<%= id %>-PatentFile" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="id_patentfile_set-<%= id %>-patentfilename">Patentfilename:</label> 
    <input id="id_patentfile_set-<%= id %>-patentfilename" maxlength="60" 
    name="patentfile_set-<%= id %>-patentfilename" type="text" />
    </p>

    <input id="id_patentfile_set-<%= id%>-patentidea" type="hidden" 
            name="patentfile_set-<%= id%>-patentidea" />
    <input id="id_patentfile_set-<%= id%>-id" type="hidden" 
   name="patentfile_set-<%=   enter code hereid%>-id" />
</div>
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

######################### END patentidea_save.html

Comment: I just posted the relevant parts of the code. Please take a look at it. Many thanks!

Comment: your problem is probably within your jquery or html code, I suggest to add the jquery tag to your post